# "NSAttributedString initWithData: options: documentAttribute: error:" not working as expected

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts, ios7, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to fill a UITableView with HTML strings. Getting the strings, putting them into cell etc. everything is ok. And I want to change my NSAttributedText's font and font size. I wrote the code below.

I checked the code via the first NSLog, if my UIFont is in the dictionary as expected; so it is in the dictionary. still no problem. but my font and font size is not changing on runtime. There is no console error. Just not working.

Second NSLog is for checking the attributedString's font and size. It says, **my string is "Times New Roman" with fontSize:12**. But as you will see in the code, I'm trying to make it **"Verdana" with Size 15**

Can anyone help me about this? Thanks.

PS: I'm keeping the strings in some objects. **obj.name** is the string which I want to write into table cell.
Html strings have some unwanted tags, so the function **[self clearTheHtml:obj.name]** function is clearing them.

```
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:15];
    [attributes setObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    NSString *s = [self clearTheHtml:obj.name];
    NSLog(@"%@", [attributes objectForKey:NSFontAttributeName]); //to see if my font is not in the dictionary. 
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[s dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:&attributes error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", attributedString);

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

EDIT:

here is the NSString *s :

```
2014-01-25 07:38:04.527 KadirB[7483:70b] 
&#39;&#39;Narakas 2013 Brachial Plexus Surgery Symposıum&#39;&#39; 23-25 Mayıs 2013 tarihleri arasında Montreux, İsvi&ccedil;re de yapıldı. Brakial Plexus sorunlarına y&ouml;nelik son gelişmeler toplantıda tartışıldı.
```

Comment: Can you produce an example of the HTML that exists in "s"?

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner  I edited and added the NSString *s.. Check pls. My htmlCleaner erases the <style> and <span> tags.  There is no font or font-size coming with html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had the same problem just a couple of days ago. I solved by simply changing the implementation like so:

```
...
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = ...;
[attributedString addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font} range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
```

I hope it helps you as well.

Comment: Sorry, it's still same. No luck.

Comment: SORYY SORRYYY!!! My fault.. When I tried, I was awake for 5 minutes.. I have done a mistake and didn't worked. But now it's ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: Not a perfect solution, as it overrides **bold** tags. Here's a solution that maintains bold text - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921972/parsing-html-into-nsattributedtext-how-to-set-font