# UIFont is automatically set to TimesNewRoman

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

```swift
func parseHtmlString(info: String, label: UILabel) {
    if let data = info.data(using: .utf8) {
        let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSMutableAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)

        let dynamicFontSize: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/22.0

        attributedString?.enumerateAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString?.length ?? 0), options: []) { (value, range, stop) in
            if let currentFont = value as? UIFont {
                let dynamicSize = currentFont.withSize(dynamicFontSize)
                attributedString?.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: dynamicSize], range: range)
                
                label.attributedText = attributedString
                label.numberOfLines = 0
                label.textAlignment = .center
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to parse the HTML string for UILabel here.
At the line, `if let currentFont = value as? UIFont`, it automatically assigns `value = times new roman` as UIFont. I want it to be system font.
If I add the line `let dynamicSize = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)`, the HTML string is not parsing and shows the output as a normal string.
Can anyone please help me? I tried different ways, but no luck.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Show the HTML string you used, the output you got, and the output you got with `let dynamicSize = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)`. Include screenshots to explain what you mean by "the HTML string is not parsing and shows the output as a normal string".

Comment: You defined your attributed string as html (`documentType: NSMutableAttributedString.DocumentType.html`) so you need to set fonts for it like you do for HTML, not like you do for native parts of the app. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396779/b-tag-not-working-in-uilabel-attributed-string) - it' an old question, but answers are still relevant.

Comment: Why are you setting the label's `attributedText`, `numberOfLines`, and `textAlignment` over and over in the loop? Just set them once after the enumeration.