# Multiple bold tags in NSMutableAttributedString with loop?

Tags: c#, ios, string, xamarin, while-loop

I have a string which contains multiple `<b>` tags and I am trying to get the text inside bold and then removing the bold tags which works fine if it only contains one `<b>` tag. Now when the string contains multiple `<b>` tags I am trying to loop them but it only catches the first one. Can someone point me to the right direction what it is that I am doing wrong here?

```
string descriptionBody = "This is a <b>text</b> with multiple <b>bold</b> tags";
var content = new NSMutableAttributedString(descriptionBody);

int i = 0;
while (i < Regex.Matches(descriptionBody, "<b>").Count) {
    int start = descriptionBody.IndexOf("<b>", StringComparison.Ordinal);
    int end = descriptionBody.IndexOf("</b>", StringComparison.Ordinal);
    int length = end - start;

    var boldFirst = new NSRange(start, 3);
    var boldLast = new NSRange(end, 4);

    StringExtensions.ParseBoldTags(content, 14, start + 3, length - 3);
    content.Replace(boldLast, string.Empty);
    content.Replace(boldFirst, string.Empty);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I would advise against [attempting to parse HTML with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4416750).

Comment: That was my first idea, but if I parse it to HTML in iOS it comes with a new times roman font, it's important to only parse the bold tags

Comment: What does parsing HTML have to do with iOS or fonts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921972/parsing-html-into-nsattributedtext-how-to-set-font

Comment: AngleSharp is a much better tool for parsing HTML

Answer (score 0):

Your start/end values are the same for each match loop. You can use the `Group` object of the `MatchCollection` to obtain each index and length of the match.

```
string descriptionBody = "This is a <b>text</b> with multiple <b>bold</b> tags";
var content = new NSMutableAttributedString(descriptionBody);

foreach (Group match in Regex.Matches(descriptionBody, "<b>"))
{
    int start = match.Index;
    int end = match.Index + match.Length;
    var boldEnd = Regex.Matches(descriptionBody.Substring(end), "</b>")[0];
    //~~~
}
```

Update:

If your end goal is to strip the bold tags and create a NSAttributedString without any markup, your can just use `Regex.Replace` instead:

```
var strippedStr = Regex.Replace(descriptionBody, "<b>|</b>", "");
var content = new NSAttributedString(strippedStr);
```

Comment: This code will only bold the <b> tags but not the text inside these tags

Comment: @Jan You just need to grab the next end bold match, I added another Match to my example to help.

Comment: I am really getting confused here lol, I guess I need more coffee

Comment: @Jan See my update, is this all you are trying to do?

Comment: No, the text also needs to be bold inbetween, otherwise it makes no sense actually

Comment: @Jan Your code is just replacing the tags with `string.Empty`.