# How to preserve the attribute of Label that will receive an HTML text

Tags: ios

In Android, when I set my text as below

```
my_text.text = Html.fromHtml("<B>From</B> Someone", FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
```

I will get

[image]

And when I just change the attribute in the `TextView` as below

```
        android:textColor="#F40"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
```

I will get

[image]

Which is cool, as I could control my attribute from the XML, while the text could come from some end point services (to control to either bold or not bold the text).

I could do similar task on iOS using the following code

```
let htmlString = "<B>From</B> someone"
let data = htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode)! 
let attrStr = try? NSAttributedString( 
  data: data,
  options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
  documentAttributes: nil)
myLabel.attributedText = attrStr
```

It always resulted as

[image]

It no longer honor the attribute set from the interface builder. Is there a way where I could still have the Label keep the attributes (font type, size, color) set by the interface builder, while the text set to it is will decide what to bold or not using `<b></b>` tag?

Comment: Try using NSAttributedString. This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921972/parsing-html-into-nsattributedtext-how-to-set-font

Comment: The above code I show is already using `NSAttributedString`